# Tumblr Theme Help: I've got the idea down, but I'm not sure where I went wrong in coding the content

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I'm trying to create a Tumblr Theme "from scratch" for the first time. I have some knowledge of html. I'm not sure where I went wrong, but I have a feeling it has something to do with placing the  in the wrong place.

The site is http://www.87Ninety.tumblr.com, pass: 1212.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what the problem is.

In your template, the `<div class="post">` is missing it's closing `</div>` tag.

Because of this, every post is contained inside the previous post and things break.

So add it back in.